# Django: Parent table having multiple inline tables linked using foreignkey from parent to each inline table

Tags: django, postgresql, foreign-key-relationship

I am creating a set of models in a way that certain models can contain details from multiple parent classes. My project requires me to have these main classes:

```
-- {class name} {file name they are contained in}
-- Attraction (attraction.py)
-- Tours (tours.py)
-- Transit (transit.py)
-- Flight (flight.py)
-- Accomodation (accomodation.py)
```

Each one of them has multiple common fields, which are modelled into common models ; I want to have foreign key from the classes above to the ones below:

```
-- Contact (contact.py)
-- Address (address.py)
-- LocationMetadata (location.py)
-- Duration (duration.py)
-- Price (price.py)
```

I made foreign key from

```
attraction --> contact, address, location, price

transit --> location, price

accomodation --> location, type, price, contact, address
```

Example Model Atraction :

```
class Attraction(models.Model):
    ...

    ATTRACTION_TYPE = (
       ('NIGHT-LIFE', 'NL'),
       ('EARTERY', 'EAT'),
       ('CULTURAL', 'CUL'),
       ('LANDMARK', 'LNDMRK'),
       ('ADVENTURE', 'ADV'),
       ('ENTERTAINMENT', 'ENT'),
       ('SCENIC', 'SNC'),
       ('WILDLIFE', 'WDL')
    )

    type = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=ATTRACTION_TYPE)
    ...
```

I want to create the admin access to have ( attraction, transit, accomodation) as access points and rest to be inline to them. But this is not permitted in Django... is there a way to go around it???

Comment: Post your models.  Hard to help without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proved to be the best solution for what i needed to do.

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield
```

It provides a multiselect field inside model itself; and adds all the selected entries as csv's .

Answer (score 1):

**(Edited after comments.)**

It sounds like you want to use InlineModelAdmins, but on the model that is linked to by ForeignKey.

The first thing you need to do is change the ForeignKey fields to OneToOneFields.  This is necessary because otherwise you could have, say, the same Address model instances appearing on multiple Attraction forms.  By the looks of it, OneToOneField is a better database structure for this use case anyway.

The second thing you need to do is to override the admin so that it allows the OneToOneField on the other model.  I haven't used it, but [this snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2032/) looks like it would do the trick.

Comment: if we model it this way.. then it keyerror pops up.. as django asks for a foreign key from Location to Attraction (and all others)...

Comment: It should work if you move the ForeignKey fields to the models you want to appear inline.  So you'd have an attraction field on the Address model, rather than an address field on the Attraction model.  Is that an option?

Comment: that is fine... thats what i want to achieve... but then i cant make foreign key from those( contact, location  etc.) to all others ( attraction, tours, accomodation etc). Even if i did that... my models would have cyclic imports(python doesnt support that), or two way foreign keys. which do not make sense to me.

Comment: Gotcha!  That's a little trickier, but I've edited my answer to give you a possible way.

Comment: thanks a lot!! i was looking for something like this... i will see if it works

Comment: Pleasure.  Feel free to accept my answer if it works!

Comment: your way needed me to remodel my schema connections in a way i didnt require. I posted a solution, which works perfectly for my case.. thanks for your help!